# Скрытие Iframe после клика вне него

Tags: html, iframe, javascript

Например вот на этом [сайте](http://www.avangard77.ru/kvartiry-s-remontom/Komsomolskii-prospekt-d-27/65/) при нажатии на клавишу 3D тур, выходит окно, при нажатии вне области окно закрывается. Как и в любых фото-галереях.
Есть ли готовые решения для этого? Хочу поместить в это окно флеш.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://fancybox.net/

> FancyBox is a tool for displaying images, html content and multi-media in a Mac-style "lightbox" that floats overtop of web page. 
>  It was built using the jQuery library. Licensed under both MIT and GPL licenses

Comment: light box получается тоже можно изменить под эти цели?

Comment: Можно, но в fancy для этого уже все готово